# Blackberry HttpPost null pointer exception Java

Tags: blackberry, nullpointerexception, http-post

With the following code, the server is getting hit, but I also want to send variables in POST method.

But it just gives me a null pointer exception. It has something to do with the `OutputStream`.   I have checked `postData` ... it has some address, which means it is not null.

So why I am given null pointer exception?

```java
ConnectionFactory connFact = new ConnectionFactory();
ConnectionDescriptor connDesc;
try {
    connDesc = connFact.getConnection("http://example.com/login.php", Connector.READ_WRITE, returnContent);
    httpConn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    URLEncodedPostData encPostData = new URLEncodedPostData("UTF-8", false);
    encPostData.append("count", "Hell Yeah!");
    byte[] postData = encPostData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

    httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-length", String.valueOf(postData.length));
    Dialog.alert("Post Data: " + postData);

    OutputStream os = httpConn.openOutputStream();
    os.write(postData);
    os.flush();
    httpConn = (HttpConnection) connDesc.getConnection();

    final int iResponseCode = httpConn.getResponseCode();
    UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            //Dialog.alert("Response code: " +  Integer.toString(iResponseCode));
        }
    });
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Caught IOException: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: which line you getting error ?

Comment: In this line: httpConn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);

Comment: Where on earth are you declaring the variable `httpConn`? Shouldn't you be calling `connDesc.getConnection` instead?

Comment: It was above the ConnectionFactory, HttpConnection httpConn;
And no its working fine: connFact.getConnection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are misusing the `ConnectionFactory.getConnection(String url, int transportType, String ConnectionUID)` method. For instance, check what you pass as `transportType`...

Here is what API says about return value:

> Returns: a ConnectionDescriptor if a connection can be established;
>   null otherwise

So, it just fails and returns `null`. And that's why you get a NPE.

**UPDATE**:

I would recommend to just use a simpler API `ConnectionFactory.getConnection(String url)`:

```
ConnectionDescriptor cd = connFact.getConnection("http://example.com/login.php");
if (cd == null) {
    // throw an error signalling there is no connectivity right now
}
HttpConnection httpConn = (HttpConnection) cd.getConnection();
// the rest of the code working with httpConn ..
```

Comment: What should be in the ConnectionUID and transportType, if you can give a example I would appreciate!

Comment: Check the UPDATE section, basically you can pass bothering with details (such as what transport to use) to the underlying APIs and just use `ConnectionFactory.getConnection(String url)` method.

Comment: BTW, note that in your code `httpConn = (HttpConnection) connDesc.getConnection()` goes too late (after `os.flush()`).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look to the linked answer and verify if that implementation of 'login' procedure is ok for your needs: 
[authentication username password url in blackberry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11294892/authentication-username-password-url-in-blackberry/11305561#11305561)